# How do I create a query to display checklist from the following tables?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Using sql server 2008, I need a query to display the following results

```
 User_Name        Group_Name          Checked
 user1              Lead                 0
 user1              Admin                1
 user1              Supervisor           0
 user1              Monitor              0
 user2              Lead                 0
 user2              Admin                0
 user2              Supervisor           1
 user2              Monitor              1
```

**I have 4 groups (Lead, Admin, Supervisor, monitor) and the linking table is User Group. How do I get all groups displayed for each user (like above)? if group is checked for a user it appears in the User Group, not in the table if unchecked.**

The tables:

**User:**

```
User_ID int
User_Name nvarchar
Email nvarchar
```

**Group:**

```
Group_ID int
Group_Name nvarchar
```

**User Group:**

```
User_ID int, 
Group_ID int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select User.User_Name, Group.Group_Name,
 case when UserGroup.User_ID is null then 0 else 1 end as Checked
from User cross join Group
 left join UserGroup on User.User_ID = UserGroup.User_ID
   and Group.Group_ID = UserGroup.Group_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use the [`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator which will assign every `group` value to each `user`, then you can join on the `usergroup` table:

```
select u.user_name,
  g.group_name,
  case when ug.user_id is not null then 1 else 0 end Checked
from [user] u
cross apply [group] g
left join usergroup ug
  on u.user_id = ug.user_id
  and g.group_id = ug.group_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44b0b/10)